# Why am I getting this warning when I add the target to my UIButton in my controller? (the warning and code is stated below)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I am programmatically creating a button and am receiving this warning for every button I create when I add the "button.addTarget" line of code to it. The code is below:

```
let logoutButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Log Out", for: .normal)
        button.setWidth(width: 100)
        button.setHeight(height: 30)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogOut), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

The warning I am getting for this is:
'self' refers to the method 'HomeController.self', which may be unexpected

And it also comes with a fix, which is:
Use 'HomeController' to silence this warning

However, when I implement this fix, the "self" in the first parameter of the "button.addTarget" line becomes "HomeController.self" and makes the app crash.

I always used to use "self" for this and it never gave warnings until recently. Now it gives a warning for this every time. When I use "self," it all still works fine, but the warnings in Xcode are annoying... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lazy var instead of let it will solve problem or set target in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a variable and assigning the result of a closure to that variable. That closure's code executes before any instances of your class exist (Before there is a `self` to refer to.)

Self does not exist at the time that code runs.

As Abhishek suggests in their answer (voted) if you switch your declaration to a lazy var, lazy vars get created the first time they are referenced. `self` exists when a lazy var's value is computed.